# SMTP pro for sending email in magento

Tags: php, magento, smtp, magento-1.7

I have downloaded SMTP pro extention for magento but cannot understand where to place this folder under my magento root directory. Help me please.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly install using Magento Connect in admin panel...
Do some Google before ask something here.